# Paperclip validations on multiple fields - wrong number of arguments (given 3, expect 1..2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple fields I'm using with paperclip and whenever I try to combine them into one for validation like below:

```
has_attached_file :staff_photo, :group_photo, 
 styles: { medium: '300x300>', thumb: '100x100>' },
 default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png'
```

I end up with: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2).

It does work when I do:

```
validates_attachment :staff_photo, :group_photo,
 content_type: {content_type: ['image/jpeg']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use several attachments at once in the definition.
If you look at the code:

```
def has_attached_file(name, options = {})
  HasAttachedFile.define_on(self, name, options)
end
```

source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/321807573451b0e656a40a12979a7684e7dab2f6/lib/paperclip.rb#L196

The method is defined for one attachment. You won't be able to use it with more than one. Write multiple statements for multiple attachments.

You can reuse the `options` by extracting them into a variable, constant or method.